# How to transfer files using ibm web sphere message queue in .net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, ibm-mq

I am using IBM WebSphere Message Queue for transferring my messages in .NET. Now I want to send some files using the message queue, is it is possible to send all file formats? And how can I send them using .NET?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I think.

1) Use WebSphere MQ Managed File Transfer (WMQMFT) product to transfer files. WMQMFT is a product built on top of WMQ. More details [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/wmqfte_intro.htm)

2) Write your own .NET application that

```
a) At the sender end, reads the file data
b) Attach the file data as message body to one or more messages. 
c) Send message(s) to a queue. 
d) At the receiver end, receive message(s) from the queue.
e) Assemble messages and write to a file.
```

Answer (score 0):

WMQ does not care what the message data is.  Therefore, read the file then send it as a message but remember that the "default" maximum message size is 4MB.  Your MQAdmin can change the maximum message size to a maximum of 100MB.

If you need to transfer files greater than 100MB than you will need to use WMQ MFT or the open source project: Universal File Mover.  http://www.capitalware.biz/ufm_overview.html